# How to remove tracked formatted changes

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have been following the msdn-guide to remove tracked changes from a docx document: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850844.aspx)

However it doesnt remove tracked formatted changes thats been made to the document. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came across this neat little class that removes all tracked changes from a document:
[accept revisions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/07/13/using-the-open-xml-sdk-and-linq-to-xml-to-accept-revisions-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessing-document.aspx) and I now use this one instead of the suggested method from the mentioned msdn post.